# JSON as DataStream?

Tags: apache-flink

I am new using Apache Flink and I am quite lost at this point, let's see if you can help me.

Context: I have a JSON from a webpage (I get it using the URL) and I was able to parse it and get the information that I needed. That JSON is constantly changing and I will need to read it continuously and "translate" the information that I need too.

I am trying to create a program, which gets the JSON, it takes the 3 or 4 attributes that I need from that JSON, it just simply shows the information on the screen, and that information is readed constantly changing or not depending on the JSON.

Using Apache Flink, which is the best approach that I should use to get the relevant information that I need? Do I need to define the JSON url as my DataStream (implementing my own SourceFunction I suppose)? In that case, Should I parse the JSON later in order to get the attributes that I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can certainly implement a `SourceFunction` that repeatedly reads JSON data from an URL. You can do the parsing either in the `SourceFunction` or a subsequent `MapFunction`, the latter is a bit more modular. However, from your description I am not sure if your use case is a good fit for Apache Flink. Flink is a distributed system designed for advanced analysis of millions of events per second at low latency. I would guess it is easier to realize your use case with a less complex system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree, what I am trying to do is quite simple for Apache Flink I know, but it is just a proof of concept, because it is possible to do the same with much more sources. I am using Apache Flink just because I want to learn about Big Data and streaming.